# JUnit test to check whether the triangle is a rectangular

Tags: java, unit-testing, geometry

We have an interface Rtriangle.

```
public interface Rtriangle {

 int getApexX1();

 int getApexY1();

 int getApexX2();

 int getApexY2();

 int getApexX3();

 int getApexY3();
}
```

There are class

```
public final class RtriangleProvider {

public static Rtriangle getTriangle() {

    return new Rtriangle() {            
        @Override
        public int getApexY3() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getApexY2() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getApexY1() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getApexX3() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getApexX2() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getApexX1() {
            return 1;
        }
    };
 }
}
```

Need to write a test that checks a rectangular triangle or not. If not, should output an error.
I wrote a sample test, but that is not the case.

```
public class TriangleTest {

@Test
public void testGetTriangle() {
    Rtriangle rt = RtriangleProvider.getTriangle();

    int x1 = rt.getApexX1();
    int x2 = rt.getApexX2();
    int x3 = rt.getApexX3();
    int y1 = rt.getApexY1();
    int y2 = rt.getApexY2();
    int y3 = rt.getApexY3();

    int side1 = (x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1);
    int side2 = (x3 - x2) * (x3 - x2) + (y3 - y2) * (y3 - y2);
    int side3 = (x1 - x3) * (x1 - x3) + (y1 - y3) * (y1 - y3);

    boolean hypo1 = (side1 == (side2 + side3));
    boolean hypo2 = (side2 == (side1 + side3));
    boolean hypo3 = (side3 == (side1 + side2));

    boolean result = hypo1 || hypo2 || hypo3;

    if (!result) {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }
}
}
```

Maybe I'm not correctly calculate the parties. 
Help please.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether your triangle satisfy the [pythagoras theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) or not here.

Same thing you are doing here.

You should be able to create different points(3 sets of coordinates). Then you can use this logic.

In your case all all three points are same `(1,1)`. This is not a triangle. You can try as following

Now you have to be smart.

```
boolean result = hypo1 || hypo2 || hypo3; // by pythagoras theorem only one 
                                          // should true
```

can't all are `true`

Change

```
  boolean result = hypo1 || hypo2 || hypo3;
```

To

```
  boolean result=false;
  boolean[] all = { hypo1, hypo2,hypo3 };   
  boolean result=false;
  for (boolean a : all) {
     for (boolean b: all) {
        for(boolean c:all){
           result =(a^b^c) && !(a&&b&&c);
          }
     }
  }
```

Why?

```
  boolean result = hypo1 || hypo2 || hypo3;// this will give you true 
                                           // for all 3 variables are true
```

That is incorrect. you have to drop that case as `false`.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. The coordinates can be arbitrary. 
But here the problem is just that this test passes for some reason. He does not throw an error about infidelity.

Comment: @Vasiliy you can try my suggestion.

Comment: i don't think so...boolean result = hypo1 || hypo2 || hypo3; is ok as if a2+b2=c2 -->hypo1-->true  if a2+c2=b2 -->hypo2-->true and so on.so if one hypo is true that mean it's rectangular triangle .

Comment: @PiumiWandana Not really. `result = hypo1 || hypo2 || hypo3` will give you `true`,when all three variable are `true`. That case is it a right angled triangle ?

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera really? could you tell me the output of this  System.out.println(true||false||false);

Comment: Here, the condition "or". 
Ie either hypo1 or hypo2 hypo3 or not true, then the error

Comment: Still, it must not at this condition, and calculating the sides. Rather, there is a mistake, in consequence of which can not be found right hypotenuse.

Comment: @PiumiWandana try to understand the issue here, this is not the case `true||false||false`, but `true||true||true`. Both cases result is `true`. But second case is not a right angled triangle. You should figure out the issue here before jump into conclusions.

Comment: I think I found the right solution.

_ assertTrue((side1 + side2 > side3)
    && (side2 + side3 > side1)
    && (side3 + side1 > side2));_